# SAML token and service calls

Tags: authentication, active-directory, saml

I am working on a tablet application and have come across an interesting issue.

We have a domain joined tablet that runs a Windows Store Application. We already have user identity and we need to call a web service endpoint that is secured with SAML.

Do I need to hit IDP to get a SAML token and pass that with my web service calls? Or would an identity object be enough to get my callers identity context?

The web service is a SAP service, that only accepts SAML.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter that you have the identity unless you are a trusted idp for the service that's protecting its resource with SAML. That said, if you have a SAML response from an idp that the service trusts, then you should be able to post that to them as an sso token.

Comment: Thanks jbd. I understand that once I am able to connect to Idp i will be able to POST. My concern is that if i can create a SAML token out of a kerberos token that i get after user gets authenticated on AD ?